# Javascript acts_as_votable gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Ok so I'm using the acts_as_votable gem to allow users to add/remove books from a collection. I would like for the add/remove buttons to work without reloading the page but cannot find anywhere implementing the button this way, just using it as a vote counter. I don't care to count votes, just add/remove. My assumption is I would have to add fave.js.erb and unfave.js.erb with appropriate javascript code, but what exactly? Thanks in advance!

Here are the actions from the controller:

```
def fave
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
current_user.likes @book
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to :back }
  format.json
  format.js
end
end
def unfave
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
current_user.dislikes @book
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to :back }
  format.json
  format.js
end
end
```

And the routes.rb

```
resources :books do
get "book/:page", :action => :index, :on => :collection
member do
  post "fave", to: "books#fave"
  post "unfave", to: "books#unfave"
end
end
```

Then from the view they are called like so:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<ul class="list-inline text-center">
<% if current_user.voted_up_for? @book %>
<li><%= button_to unfave_book_path(@book, method: :put, remote: true), class: "btn btn-default btn-danger", title: "Remove from Collection", data: {disable_with: "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span> Removing..."} do %>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span>  Remove from Collection
<% end %>
</li>
<% else %>
<li><%= button_to fave_book_path(@book, method: :put, remote: true), class: "btn btn-default btn-success", title: "Add to Collection", data: {disable_with: "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> Adding..."} do %>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>  Add to Collection
<% end %>
</li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, I would show and hide the buttons based on the user's voting status. And then show/hide them when the user adds/removes them.

```
<ul class="list-inline text-center">
  <li data-book-id="<%= @book.id %>">
    <%= button_to unfave_book_path(@book, method: :put, remote: true), class: "btn btn-default btn-danger unfave #{'hidden' unless current_user.voted_up_for?(@book)}", title: "Remove from Collection", data: {disable_with: "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span> Removing..."} do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span>  Remove from Collection
    <% end %>
    <%= button_to fave_book_path(@book, method: :put, remote: true), class: "btn btn-default btn-success fave #{'hidden' if current_user.voted_up_for?(@book)}", title: "Add to Collection", data: {disable_with: "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> Adding..."} do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>  Add to Collection
    <% end %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm also assuming that you might have multiple `li`s for different books.

in the **fave.js.erb**, you could do:

```
var $li = $("li[data-book-id='<%= @book.id %>']");
$li.find('button.unfave').show();
$li.find('button.fave').hide();
```

And in **unfave.js.erb**, you could do:

```
var $li = $("li[data-book-id='<%= @book.id %>']");
$li.find('button.fave').show();
$li.find('button.unfave').hide();
```

If you really want to keep your template the way it is, you could just re-render the partial:

```
$('ul.list-inline').html("<%= j render 'path/to/a/partial', book: @book %>");
```

Comment: Still does not load asynchronously though. Could this be an issue with turbolinks?

Comment: Probably not. I don't think turbolinks listens to requests besides GETs. Try putting an alert in your js templates to make sure they're rendering. If so, you might need to tweak the jquery. If not, look at your server logs and see what template the request is rendering.